# Can you install a heat pump with 4 wires?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, heat-pump

I currently have a central AC system.  I'm looking into replacing it with a variable speed one.  I've been told that if I'm replacing it anyways, I should look into getting a heat pump instead for a bit more so I get an alternate heating option.

Looking at my thermostat wiring, it's only a 4-wire cable and they're all used up.  Is a heat pump even an option for me to consider?

Comment: How is your heat currently controlled?

Comment: Are you OK with replacing your existing thermostat?

Comment: Thermostat wiring can also be replaced...

Comment: Typical heat pumps generally require 8 conductor cables to the tstat. You'll almost certainly need to replace the tstat as well and maybe some upgrades to the air handler.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes but I got a Honeywell T9 which I think supports a heat pump.

Comment: You'll want a thermostat smart enough to make economic decisions about whether the heat pump or gas is cheaper to run right now.  It needs to know the temperature outside.  How does a modern thermostat know the temperature outside? It logs onto your WiFi and queries the temperature at your local airport or weather station. Every town has one. Sometimes six.

Comment: @Jack -- yeah, you may wish to look at a different 'stat (Honeywell *used* to make one that was ideal for these scenarios, and still does if you don't mind another wireless gizmo in your house, while Aprilaire has one that could work OK as well I think) -- the t-stats that work well here generally have an interface module connected via a data bus or RF link to the thermostat control on the wall